# Can not get the token with localhost url in rest assured

Tags: java, post, localhost, rest-assured

I am new at testing using rest assured. In postman it works fine and can return the token. But, when I used rest assured to get the token it return 404 in status code and "error":"unauthorized" in body response.
Here is my code

```
 RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();
 Response res = request
            //.contentType("application/json")
            .queryParam("username", "uname")
            .queryParam("password", "password")
            .queryParam("cliend_id", "android")
            .queryParam("grant_type", "password")
            .queryParam("scope", "trust")
            .post("http://localhost:8080/com.abcde.webservices/oauth/token");
 System.out.println("Response : "+res.asString());
 System.out.println(res.getStatusCode());
```

I already try using

```
 RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:8080/com.abcde.webservices";
 .....
 .post("/oauth/token");
```

But still can't get the token

Comment: You are not posting the form body. Use `formParam` instead of `queryParam`.

Comment: I want to make the url like localhost:8080/com.abcde.webservices/oauth/token?username=uname&password=password&client_id=android&grant_type=password&scope=trust. will it work using formParam ?

Comment: Then you should use `get`. `queryParam` for `get`, `formParam` for `post`. See the [doc](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#specifying-request-data) for details.

Comment: get 401 status code now

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I got miss typing it in clint_id. I type cliend_id, and it should be client_id. Everything works fine after I changed it.